# Crystal report exception cannot be caught

Tags: c#, exception, crystal-reports

There

I have a crystal report issue: If the crystal report component is not installed (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll cannot be found) in customer environment, the exception cannot be caught in code snippet 1, but can be caught in snippet 2

Code snippet 1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                var rtDocument = new ReportDocument();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              //The exception cannot be caught if Crystal report environment is broken or not installed.
                Console.WriteLine("Exception......");
            } 
    }
```

Code snippet 2:

```
public class ReportDialog:Form
{
    public ReportDialog()
    {
        var a = new ReportDocument();
        Console.WriteLine("ReportDocument OK");
    }
}
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                var d = new ReportDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              //The exception can be caught if crystal report component is broken or not installed

                Console.WriteLine("Exception......");
            } 
    }
```

The question is: I want to know how to catch the exception in code snippet 1

Comment: The question is I want to know how to catch the exception in code snippet 1

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine to "Copy Local" when you deploy the application so the references will be installed with your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually we have make the crystal report into installation package of our product. The problem I need to resolve is to make sure the application running well, but give a message to user while CR component broken or not installed, but not crash.